# Confirm drush is reading policy file

Tags: drush

Drush newbie question: I've copied the policy.drush.inc file from [drush examples](http://www.drush.org/en/master/examples/) and saved into my local drush folder, then cleared drush's cache - how do I confirm Drush is using that file (other than attempting to overwrite a production database with a local one!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `examples/policy.drush`.inc contains a `drush_policy_pm_update_validate` hook. If `drush pm-update`, gives you the message "This codebase is assembled with Composer instead of Drush. [...]" you know that Drush uses the file.

Comment: I'm not seeing that message - where should I be when I run drush pm-update? I've done 'drush status' to double-check where my drush is installed, and confirmed that policy.drush.inc is in the same directory (so it's alongside drush.php).

Comment: OK, moved policy.drush.inc into commands directory in drush, cleared drush cache and I now see the "This codebase..." message - so it's working - thank you!